# SQL: delete records depends on a two variables conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-delete

depends on the below:

```
Rank  Provincecode provincekey   Name   Value  
 1         ABC        100       address  Detriot
 1         ABC        100        city     NULL
 1         ABC        100        country  US
 1         ABC        100         region   US
 5         ABC        200        address   NULL
 5         ABC        200          city    NULL
 5         ABC        200         Region   NULL
 5         ABC         200        country  NULL   
 9         XYZ         500        address  Texas
 9         XYZ         500        city      TX
 9         xyz         500         country  US
 9         XYZ         500         Region   US
```

The requirement is to delete the records grouped by the raked
with these two conditions:

- the group has the lowest rank
- one of the group's records has the `Value` column not null

***If the second condition does not pass we try with the second-lowest rank and check the `value` value if it contains any not null value. and so on ***

Desired results only low ranking records should be considered irrespective of the block values are null or not null.

o/p :

```
 1         ABC        100       address  Detriot
 1         ABC        100        city     NULL
 1         ABC        100        country  US
 1         ABC        100         region   US
```

Tried something like this

```
DELETE CTE FROM  
      (
      SELECT RANK() OVER(Partition BY NAME ORDER BY Rank Asc, Date Desc, key Desc) AS RNK,FName,Name,Value,Code,key,Date
      FROM #TABLE1  SRC WHERE code = 'ABC' AND FName = 'CITY' AND (ISNULL(Value,'') <> '') 
           UNION 
      SELECT RANK() OVER(Partition BY FName ORDER BY Rank Asc, Date Desc, key Desc) AS RNK,FName,Name,Value,Code,key,Date
      FROM #TABLE1  SRC WHERE code = 'ABC' AND FName = 'CITY' AND (ISNULL(Value,'') = '')   
     ) CTE

     WHERE ((RNK > 1 AND FName = 'ABC' AND (ISNULL(Value,'') <> '')) OR (FName = 'CITY' AND (ISNULL(Value,'') = '')))
```

It is thowing an error. Can any one provide help on this.

Comment: Desired results would be a big help.

Comment: Please delete the above comment and instead include this information in your question.

Comment: how to delete and and which information i need to include? @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: @kishorekumar: you can [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59359731/edit) and add the results that you would expect as formatted text.

Comment: PLease show the desired output from the sample data you've provided

Comment: Apply tow condition on the records that will not be deleted :
***1-*** the records must have the lowest rank.
***2-*** one of the lowest rank record group must have not null value .  

is that what you want ?

Comment: @shrembo Yes you are right

Comment: Is there a difference between `TABLE` and `TABLE2` in that query? And there's no `MODIFIEDDATE` in the sample data?

Comment: @LukStorms both are the same.ranking done on modified date.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are over-complicating your logic in your question.

If you need to delete values regardless of their `null` status then just use a `where` and exclude the null conditions:

```
delete from [source table]
where rank > 1
```

Data is either present (not null) or it isn't (null), if your criteria doesn't care, why include the logic at all?

Comment: @gbeavan. requirement is not blindly deleting the record which has highest ranking, but to verify the records which are not null(ex: country = US) and has low ranking. Retain that records and delete the rest of them. Not sure of the data which we receive but only not null values which has lowest ranking should be retained. Hope you got it

Answer (score 0):

Getting the rank seems to be the key to this puzzle.

The example below gives priority to the groups that have a country.

So if there's only 1 group, and that group has no country, then it won't be deleted.
If there are more groups then the newest group with a country will remain.

**Sample data:**

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Table1 
> (
>   ProvinceCode varchar(3) not null, 
>   ProvinceKey int not null, 
>   Name nvarchar(30) not null, 
>   [Value] nvarchar(30),
>   ModifiedDate datetime not null
> );
>
> INSERT INTO Table1
> (ProvinceCode, ProvinceKey, Name, [Value], ModifiedDate) VALUES 
>
>  ('ABC', 200, 'address', NULL, '2019-12-21')
> ,('ABC', 200, 'city', NULL, '2019-12-21')
> ,('ABC', 200, 'region', NULL, '2019-12-21')
> ,('ABC', 200, 'country', NULL, '2019-12-21')
>
> ,('ABC', 100, 'address', 'Detriot', '2019-12-15')
> ,('ABC', 100, 'city', NULL, '2019-12-15')
> ,('ABC', 100, 'country', 'US', '2019-12-15')
> ,('ABC', 100, 'region', 'US', '2019-12-15')
>
> ,('XYZ', 500, 'address', 'Texas', '2019-12-09')
> ,('XYZ', 500, 'city', 'TX', '2019-12-09')
> ,('XYZ', 500, 'country', 'US', '2019-12-09')
> ,('XYZ', 500, 'region', 'US', '2019-12-09')
> ```

**Delete:**

> ```
> WITH CTE_SLC1 AS
> (
>   SELECT *
>   , CAST(MAX(CASE WHEN Name = 'country' AND [Value] IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY ProvinceCode, ProvinceKey) AS BIT) AS hasCountry 
>   , MAX(ModifiedDate) OVER (PARTITION BY ProvinceCode, ProvinceKey) AS p_date
>   FROM Table1
> )
> , CTE_SLC2 AS
> (
>   SELECT *
>   , DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY 1-hasCountry, p_date DESC) AS p_rank
>   FROM CTE_SLC1
> )
> DELETE
> FROM CTE_SLC2
> WHERE p_rank > 1;
> ```

**What remains**

> ```
> SELECT *
> FROM Table1
> ORDER BY ProvinceCode, ProvinceKey, Name;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> ProvinceCode | ProvinceKey | Name    | Value   | ModifiedDate       
> :----------- | ----------: | :------ | :------ | :------------------
> ABC          |         100 | address | Detriot | 15/12/2019 00:00:00
> ABC          |         100 | city    | null    | 15/12/2019 00:00:00
> ABC          |         100 | country | US      | 15/12/2019 00:00:00
> ABC          |         100 | region  | US      | 15/12/2019 00:00:00
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d10973c609651bcb3ef1cdec938e88c8)*

Comment: thank you for your answer. Here the challenge is to get the ranking based on modifieddate not as per countries. Once we get the rank based on modifieddate need to verify whether country column is not null and delete the rest of the records irrespective of NULL or NOT NULL of country column.

Comment: Updated.  Now with an order by `1-hasCountry, p_date DESC` in the rank

Comment: DELETE CTE FROM  (SELECT RANK() OVER(Partition BY NAME ORDER BY Rank Asc, Date Desc, key Desc) AS RNK,FName,Name,Value,Code,key,Date FROM #TABLE1  SRC WHERE code = 'ABC' AND FName = 'CITY' AND (ISNULL(Value,'') <> '')     UNION  SELECT RANK() OVER(Partition BY FName ORDER BY Rank Asc, Date Desc, key Desc) AS RNK,FName,Name,Value,Code,key,Date FROM #TABLE1  SRC WHERE code = 'ABC' AND FName = 'CITY' AND (ISNULL(Value,'') = '') ) CTE  WHERE ((RNK > 1 AND FName = 'ABC' AND (ISNULL(Value,'') <> '')) OR (FName = 'CITY' AND (ISNULL(Value,'') ='')))
I am trying above query but its throwing an error.

Comment: Check this *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=396be8cb9440be1e2ccb9c7b2ceeb444)*.  A delete from a union doesn't work like that. One would need to join it.